# How to focus on spesific section on keyboar pops up in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm bit more thinking a bout UX in this app and wandering how I can achieve below behavior in flutter. so far what I have done is just making sections using Rows, Columns and Expanded widgets. but when the keyboard opens it overlaps content. I have my custom widgets so its simplified as below.

```
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 6,
                child: Container(
                   // Image goes here
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 5,
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 5),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                              spreadRadius: 5,
                              blurRadius: 8,
                              offset:
                                  Offset(0, 4), // changes position of shadow
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            // Form goes here
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Button(
                        label: "Sign In",
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Button(
                    label: "Don’t have an account? Sign Up",
                    type: 'text',
                    align: 'center'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Just needs to add `reverse: true` to `SingleChildScrollView` then it scroll down the `SingleChildScrollView` to bottom when focus on `TextField`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF9FDFF),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
             reverse: true, // <---- Add this
            child: Column(
                   child: // Your content
           ),
         ),
       ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, with FocusScope.of(context).hasFocus to detect if keyboard is showing or not and change my UI accordingly.